# How to pass only one row as bean from View to Controller in a dynamically created Table - Spring MVC Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

My Requirement is that i am creating table dynamically  by fetching data from Database.
I have created bean as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
public class Student {

@Id
@Column(name="rollnumber")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_Sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_Sequence", sequenceName = "STUDENT_SEQ")
private int rollnumber;
private String firstname;
private String surname;
private String address;

//I have not added Setters and Getters methods here. NO need}
```

Next below code is of my viewStudents page where i will be showing each and every student from the database. I have not used Form here.
Working of view page is that it will show all the students in a table with EDIT AND UPDATE button in the last column. If user clicks on EDIT table data for particular row would turn into EDITABLE textbox and user can edit that field than user can update that data to database using UPDATE button. 
My Requirement :- I want to send single row data as Java Bean or by anyway efficient way by keeping in mind that right now i have only 3 attributes may be in future i increase it.
Below is my viewStudent.jsp page

```
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Student List</h1>  
<table id="datatable" border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">  
<tr><th>Roll Number</th><th>First Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Address</th>
<th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>  
<c:forEach var="student" items="${list}">   
<tr>  
<td>${student.rollnumber}</td>  
<td>${student.firstname}</td>  
<td>${student.surname}</td>  
<td>${student.address}</td>  
<td><button id="editlink" type="button">Edit</button></td>
<td><a id="updatelink" href="updatetemp/${student}">Update</a></td>
<td><a id="deletelink" href="deleteemp/${student.rollnumber}">Delete</a>
</td>  
</tr>  
</c:forEach>  
</table>  
<br/>  
<a href="Home">Add New Student</a>  
</body>
</html>
```

Below is how i want my handler Code. Please suggest me what changes i need I hope you understood my requirement. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updatetemp/{s}")  
public ModelAndView edit(Student s) throws SQLException{
this.studentService.update(s);  
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewStudent");}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you put every row in their own form or do it with javascript and give all a  specific id. Then have one form with attributes that you set with javascript and submit. I would go with the form version, but wiser coders might say differently.